# Multiselect Hvplot Dropdown

Tags: python, plot, hvplot, holoviz

Want to multiselect values in hvplot dropdown.

Hi, I have been trying to create a interactive plot in python using hvplot. When I use the `groupby` argument and call a column in `dataframe.hvplot(x, y groupby=" ")`, it correctly returns a dropdown with the distinct values of the column used in groupby argument.

In the dropdown produced next to the chart, I can only select one field at a time and the graph gets updated accordingly. Here I want to select 2 or more fields so I can compare them at a single glance.

Is there any way to multi-select 2 or more values?

Here I have taken the code from [Holoviz website](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Widgets.html) and produced the plot. There are 3 species and I can only select 1 at a time.

[image: Code Screenshot]